# Counting columns within a range, that have at least one number

Tags: excel

I have a large table divided into categories by rows and by columns. The number of rows/columns in each category is irregular.
In the example below rows are divided into colors, columns are divided into groups (a, b):

[image]

In each of the rectangles created by the row\column category combinations, I need to count the number of columns that contain at least one number.
The answers should be:

[image]

What I am missing of course is the formula to put in column M above.
I started with this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($B$2:$H$9<>0)*--($A$2:$A$9=$L2)*--($B$1:$H$1=$K2))
```

This counts all the cells containing numbers within each rectangle, but I still need to break this into columns, and then not count cells, but check if **any**
cell in the column contains a number, and then count those columns.

This could be easier of course if I add another table to aggregate this part of the way and then count from the aggregated table. My question is if this is possible to do with one direct calculation? (why? cleanliness, efficiency, elegance...)

Thanks for any help figuring this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an array formula like this. It uses MMULT to find the column totals of cells that satisfy the various conditions, then SUM to find how many of those totals are greater than zero.

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW($B$2:$H$9))^0,N(($B$2:$H$9>0)*($B$1:$H$1=$A11)*($A$2:$A$9=$B11)))>0))
```

[image]

Must be entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

On reflection you can simplify it slightly to

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW($B$2:$H$9))^0,N($B$2:$H$9*($B$1:$H$1=$A11)*($A$2:$A$9=$B11)))>0))
```

and you don't need the N either because the result of the multiplications in the second part of the MMult is already a set of numbers

```
=SUM(--(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(ROW($B$2:$H$9))^0,$B$2:$H$9*($B$1:$H$1=$A11)*($A$2:$A$9=$B11))>0))
```

Comment: This works perfectly - thanks! now it took me a while to understand HOW it works ([this](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-rows-that-contain-specific-values) helped), and, from what I understand, it seems another simplification is possible - getting rid of `^0`. Any reason not to?

Comment: Good that it works for you. Yes, the reference that you quote is a useful one. You are right, no reason to keep the ^0 (you would only need it if you actually wanted column totals, but you just want to know if they are zero or not) - unless you were dealing with extremely large numbers and a very big table in which case you would face performance issues eventually anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it was easier to accomplish what you want with `COUNTIFS`. So with inputs of

[image]

I can get an output table of

[image]

With the following formula in column M:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$9,$L2,$B$2:$B$9,"<>0",$C$2:$C$9,"<>0",$D$2:$D$9,"<>0",$E$2:$E$9,"<>0",$F$2:$F$9,"<>0",$G$2:$G$9,"<>0",$H$2:$H$9,"<>0")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the function you suggest doesn't take into account the column categories. As they are dinamic, and the real data contains hundreds (sometimes thousands) of columns, this solution is not viable...